# De-duplicate a list of objects in python

Tags: python

How can I de-duplicate a list of objects in python, such that
`list_of_objects[i] is list_of_objects[j]` returns `true` if and only if `i == j`?

Example:

I have two clusters of numbers, and I build a dictionary with the number as key, and the value as cluster

```
a = {1,2,3}
b = {4,5,6}
cur_dict = {1:a, 2:a, 3:a, 4:b, 5:b, 6:b}
duplicated_clusters = list(cur_dict.values())
duplicated_clusters
# [{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6}]
# How to process duplicated_clusters to get [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]?

# Obviously set(duplicated_clusters) is not working because set is not hashable and mutable.
```

Since there is no pointer in python, how do I obtain a list of de-duplicated objects (or is it unachievable)? (I can think of some workarounds but it's not straight-forward to me, such as using extra identifiers or wrapping each object into a wrapper class).

```
# An example workaround but I want to have a more straight-forward way
a = {1,2,3}
b = {4,5,6}
cluster_dict = {"clusterA": a, "clusterB": b}
cur_dict = {1:"clusterA", 2:"clusterA", 3:"clusterA", 4:"clusterB", 5:"clusterB", 6:"clusterB"}
duplicated_cluster_names = list(cur_dict.values())
deduplicated_clusters = [cluster_dict[name] for name in set(duplicated_cluster_names)]
deduplicated_clusters
# [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]
```

Example 2:

Added an example for better clarity, thanks to @wjandrea comments.

```
a = {1,2,3}
b = {4,5,6}
c = {1,2,3}
duplicated_clusters = [a,a,b,b,c,c]
duplicated_clusters
# [{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]
# Deduplicated clusters I want to obtain: [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}], equivalent to [a,b,c]
```

Comment: Not really, what I am asking is about deduplicating the object identity. For example, `{1,2,3} is {1,2,3}`  is equal to `false` in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function returns a value that is unique and constant for the object's lifetime. You can use it as a key to identify duplicate objects.

```
a = {1,2,3}
b = {4,5,6}
cur_dict = {1:a, 2:a, 3:a, 4:b, 5:b, 6:b}
duplicated_clusters = list(cur_dict.values())
result = list({id(x): x for x in duplicated_clusters}.values())
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]
```

"there is no pointer in python" is only *mostly* true. In CPython, `id` returns the address of the object in memory, so it is effectively a pointer to that object. But this approach should work even for more exotic implementations where `id` doesn't have anything to do with memory addresses. As long as `a is b` implies `id(a) == id(b)` and vice versa, then this approach should eliminate referential duplicates.

---

... All that said, keep in mind that Python often "interns" some types of built-in values, so objects that you *think* may be referentially unique might actually be the same object. Consider the example:

```
a = {1,2,3}
b = {1,2,3}
c = (4,5,6)
d = (4,5,6)
e = int("23")           #the parser doesn't know what value this will be until runtime
f = 23
g = int("456789101112") #the parser doesn't know what value this will be until runtime
h = 456789101112
i = 456789101111+1      #the parser knows at compile time that this evaluates to 456789101112
cur_dict = {1:a, 2:b, 3:c, 4:d, 5:e, 6:f, 7:g, 8:h, 9:i}
duplicated_clusters = list(cur_dict.values())
result = list({id(x): x for x in duplicated_clusters}.values())
print(result)
```

Result (in CPython):

```
[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, (4, 5, 6), 23, 456789101112, 456789101112]
```

Sets are mutable, so they are never interned. Tuples are immutable, so they may be interned. Small ints are interned, even if you go out of your way to create them in such a way that the parser can't guess what its value is at compile-time. Large ints are usually not interned, although two large int values can still be referentially identical if they were created using arithmetic expressions that can be optimized down to a single constant at compile time.